# How to disable drupal empty comments error?

Tags: comments, redirection

I'm new to drupal.
I have created a custom module, where user can post comments for the videos.
I have used default comment module in drupal for calidation. ie(modules->comment->comment.module).
But on giving a empty comment it is showing validation in a page called (/comments....)
let us assume my page is www.drupal.com/videos
I want the validation to be shown in the same page..
Plss help

This is the custom code in comment.module

```
if (empty($comment->cid) && empty($comment->pid)) {
  $form['#action'] = url('comment/reply/' .$comment->nid);
}
```

In the url tag i've given my custom url. but it redirects to that page, 
but the empty comment error is showing in some other random page every time.

Comment: Please show your code, we can't help without that.

Comment: hi @Clive pls follow the below link for code              http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80451/how-do-i-remove-default-comment-validation-in-drupal-7

Comment: @Ajmal  It is really unclear what you are asking here, but it looks like this is the same issue as your other question, so I am closing this as a duplicate.