# How do I remove default comment validation in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, comments, forms

Drupal is showing error message for empty comments by default. how can i remove that error message.
Note:- (I have not written any custom validation. It's the default validation provided by drupal module.) My changes in comment.module

```
if (empty($comment->cid) && empty($comment->pid)) { 
if(($form['#node']->type=='iks_videos_youtube_video') || ($form['#node']-               >type=='iks_videos_vimeo_video' || $form['#node']->type=='iks_videos_video')){
if(isset($form['#node']->type) && $form['#node']->type=='iks_videos_youtube_video')
{   $vtype='yt';}
else
{   $vtype='v'; }
$form['#action'] = url('video/' . $form['#node']->video_id[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] . '/'.$vtype.'/' . strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $form['#node']->title)));
  }else{
$form['#action'] = url('comment/reply/' . $comment->nid);}
```

}

my custom module code

```
function  iks_videos_form_comment_node_iks_videos_youtube_video_form_alter(&$form, $form_estate) {
if (isset($form['actions']['preview']))
unset($form['actions']['preview']);
$form['subject']['#access'] = FALSE;
unset($form['author']['mail']['#description']);
$form['#submit'][] = '_iks_videos_comment_form_submit';
    }
```

alter form

```
function _iks_videos_comment_form_submit($form, &$form_estate) {

if(($form['#node']->type) && $form['#node']->type=='iks_videos_youtube_video')
    $vtype='yt';
else 
    $vtype='v';
$form_estate['redirect'][0] = 'video/' . $form['#node']->video_id[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] . '/'.$vtype.'/' . strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $form['#node']->title));
```

}

Comment: you musn't change any code in Drupal core modules, it's very bad hardcode. You can do all your logic that you added to `comment.module` in `hook_form_alter`.

Comment: ok @milkovsky let me change the comment.module to default settings.. Actually validation is not my problem. but the validation is showing in another page called /comment/reply. how can i make the validation show in my custom page i mentioned above

Comment: you can check add by url of page. e.g. `if(arg(0)=='node'){...}`

Comment: i tried. it is redirecting to my custom page. but the error message is not displaying there. it is displaying is some other page which i navigate next

Comment: change `#action` in form alter

Comment: i can't understand can u pls write the code??

Comment: see my update in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see error message because comment_body is required for comment entity.
You can delete `#required` parameter for `comment_body`:

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if(strpos($form_id, 'comment_node_erpal_task_form') !== FALSE) {
    $form['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#required'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

But just know that you'll have php notice then. Because posting comment without the body is not right:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in comment_submit() (line 2197 of
>   W:\home\erpal.local\www\modules\comment\comment.module).

Make sure yhat you added custom validation for body field.

You you can handle validation callbacks for the whole form in `$form['#validate']` array. Also you can handle validation callbacks for each form element in `#element_validate` array. E.g. for comment_body:

```
$form['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#element_validate'][] = '_my_module_comment_body_validate';
```

**Update**

You musn't change any code in Drupal core modules, it's very bad hardcode. You can do all your logic that you added to comment.module in hook_form_alter.

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if(strpos($form_id, 'comment_node_erpal_task_form') !== FALSE) {
    $form['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#required'] = FALSE;

    if(isset($form['#node']->type) && $form['#node']->type=='iks_videos_youtube_video') {
      $vtype='yt';
    }
    else {
      $vtype='v'; 
    }

    $url = url('video/' . $form['#node']->video_id[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] . '/'.$vtype.'/' . strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $form['#node']->title))); 
    $form['#action'] =  $url;  
  }
}
```

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/1609256  please go through the issue here. I'm asking the solution for this

Comment: the issue it's for drupal 8

Comment: @milkovsky It looks like the issue was created for Drupal 7, then assigned to Drupal 8, and a patch will be backported.  This is how most core bugs in 7 are handled right now.